# Слияние массивов с константной памятью

Tags: c++, c, массивы, алгоритм

Как слить два отсортированных массива так, чтобы результат в итоге был в них самих? Первая часть - в первом, вторая - во втором. Эффективно.

Пример входных и выходных данных

{1 3 4}, {1 2 5} => {1 1 2}, {3 4 5}

Comment: пройтись по массивам переставляя минимальный элемент из одного в другой?

Comment: @user7860670 находим минимальный в двух и переставляем его на какую позицию?

Comment: Может, вам про сортировку слиянием тогда почитать?

Comment: можно не искать - минимальный будет в начале - они же отсортированы, переставляем на позицию другого

Comment: @user7860670 ну так надо сравнить кто минимальней же. Вопрос куда ставить дальше его? Весь массив другой проходить, искать место, сдвигать? Кажется слишком долго

Comment: @gbg если это решает мою задачу, то напишите

Comment: ставить на место не минимального...

Comment: Сначала нужно разобраться с постановкой вопроса. Возможно, я даже со второго раза не понял, что вы такое хотите получить. Приведите пример входных и выходных данных. Также желательно при общении придерживаться более дружелюбного тона.

Comment: @gbg 1 3 4, 1 2 5 => 1 1 2, 3 4 5. Где вы нашли недружелюбный тон не понял

Comment: @user7860670 можете подробнее объяснить в ответе, пока не понимаю, что вы имеете в виду. Можно без кода, просто алгоритм

Comment: @Harry память константна, эффективно относительно времени

Comment: @Harry Я почти уверен, что что-то такое можно найти у Кнута в трехтомнике

Comment: Ну, O(n log n) устроит?

Comment: это же вроде избитая задача, первая же ссылка в бинге дает https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-two-sorted-arrays-o1-extra-space/

Comment: @user7860670 Забавно, там говорят об O(n*m), в то время как можно получить O((n+m)*log(n+m)) любой приличной :) сортировкой - или я неправ?...

Comment: [O((n+m)*log(n+m))](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/efficiently-merging-two-sorted-arrays-with-o1-extra-space/), [O(nlog(n)+mlog(m))](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/efficiently-merging-two-sorted-arrays-with-o1-extra-space-and-onlogn-mlogm/?ref=rp).

Comment: Может попробовать `std::views::join` вместе с `std::ranges::inplace_merge`...

Answer (score 1):

Вам попалась сложная задача. Слияние без дополнительной памяти позволяет создать стабильную сортировку без дополнительной памяти.

Одна из стабильных сортировок - сортировка слиянием. Ключевая операция в ней - слияние двух отсортированных массивов в один с использованием дополнительного буфера. Если придумать как это сделать без буфера вы получите стабильную сортировку без дополнительной памяти. Подробности тут: [Устойчивая_сортировка#Алгоритмы_сортировки_слиянием_без_дополнительной_памяти](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8)

Answer (score 0):

**Первая шляпа:**

**kuku**, массивы в памяти как правило занимают непрерывный участок памяти, поэтому к каждому элементу которого можно обращаться по смещению. В случае двух массивов - чуть не так, и первый и второй массив - могут быть разнесены в памяти.

**Вторая шляпа:**

В C++ есть и перегрузка многих итераторов, и есть функции сортировок в стандартной библиотеке. Был бы один массив - вы бы не заморачивались! А вот в случае двух массивов  - просто обеспечьте перегрузку индексного оператора, и опять же воспользуйтесь функции сортировки из стандартной библиотеки.

Да, я помню постановку задачи ... но и вы помните - у каждой "ячейки" массива есть свой адрес (скорее - адрес начала+смещение). А у вас есть перегрузки операторов взятия элемента по индексу (к примеру). И есть перегрузки взятия адреса, оло-ло-ло....

Ликбез окончен. Пишите свой код, если не получится - сообщество направит.

Пишите fake-class, который умеет ссылаться на ячейки двух массивов, читать их и писать по индексу. А стандартная либа их быстр разбросает.

**Третья шляпа:**

Применить алгоритм сортировки. Учитывая размерности 2- массивов. Опять - же поиск индекса, откуда что считать.

Comment: О, вы попались на те-же грабли, что и я. Я за аналогичный ответ отхватил от автора сразу и минус и флаг "к удалению". Автору нужно, по итогу, чтобы у него было два массива A и B, которые содержат в себе отсортированное объединение массивов A и B начальных

Comment: Не понял, причём тут расположение массивов в памяти. И как тут применить стандартный алгоритм сортировки? ТСу алгоритм слияния двух массивов с O(1) дополнительной памяти нужен...

Comment: Если два массива расположить в памяти последовательно, без "дырок", получаемых неверным выравниванием, то эти участки можно считать за один массив. Ну и принимать к нему алгоримм(ы) последующей сортировки, как к единому массиву.

Comment: Если массивы уже отсортированы, то зачем их слиять один в конец другого с последующей сортировкой. Это тупо. А O(1) к памяти какое отношение имеет? Это обозначение временной сложности. Причём не всегда по нему можно определять какой алгоритм будет лучше в конкретном случае. Потому что он сводится к бесконечности по сути, что не очень то правильно. Вернее, нужно учитывать это.